# Swift geolocation latitude and longitude separation and making into a CLLocation2DMake

Tags: swift, geolocation, coordinates

```
   func forwardGeocoding(address: String) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]
            let location = placemark?.location
            let coordinate = location?.coordinate
            print("\nlat: \(coordinate!.latitude), long: \(coordinate!.longitude)")
            if placemark?.areasOfInterest?.count > 0 {
                let areaOfInterest = placemark!.areasOfInterest![0]
                print(areaOfInterest)
            } else {
                print("No area of interest found.")
            }
        }
})


        var INITIAL_DESTINATION = forwardGeocoding(initialDestination)

        var DESIRED_DESTINATION = forwardGeocoding(desiredDestination)

        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(<#T##CLLocationDegrees#>, <#T##CLLocationDegrees#>)
```

Hello, I am trying to make a mapping app, and am having trouble with this part. What I want to do is be able to separate the `INITIAL_DESTINATION` latitude and longitudes. I have to do this to create a `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`. What I have been trying to do is just use `INITIAL_DESTINATION.latitude` and `INITIAL_DESTINATION.longitude`, but I am continuingly facing the same error which is `"Value of tuple type "()" has no member "latitude"`. This is also strange because it does not give that error for `INITIAL_DESTINATION.longitude`.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, and thank you for reading and taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns nothing, and does nothing with the value returned in the asynchronous completion handler. You need to take the asynchronous result and use it in some fashion.

Try this: Put prints at the end of the function, and inside the completion handler, then run the code. What you'll see is that the function is done before the completion handler runs, because the code inside the block does not run until the remote web site returns an answer across the network. At that time Alamofire hands the result to your code in the completion block.

You'll also need to be aware that there are multiple queues in iOS, and UI changes can only be done on the main queue. The completion block does not run on the main queue, however, so likely to use the information returned from the network you'll need to use the dispatch_async function to call a function in your program and have it execute on the main queue.

Comment: It initially gave me an error when I tried to `return coordinate?.latitude` and `return coordinate?.longitude`, because it said it was a void function, so I then tried to fix this by doing `func forwardGeocoding(address: String) -> Double` , but it still gives me an error. Any suggestions to fix that? Similarily, can you please elaborate on what I would add to the completion handler? Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: There's nothing useful for the function to return. The completion handler should call a function passing perhaps the placemark for further processing

Comment: The only thing that I want this function to do is return a latitude float value and a longitude float value, so how can I get this two values to return?

Comment: Those values are provided asynchronously to the completion handler, and are not going to be available at the time the function returns

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I honestly have no idea what you are talking about. If you can severely dumb this down for me, that would be great.

Comment: I'm going to have to see the calling code using this function to steer you towards a good answer. Can you reasonably post that?